# Affine Cipher Issue

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

I'm working through a problem where I need to decrypt a string of text that I know has been encrypted with an affine cipher. I ran a frequency analysis on the letters of the text and Y & W are the most frequent with Y appearing 11 times and W appearing 8.

So I assumed that

- e --> Y or 4 --> 24
- t --> W or 19 --> 22

This was wrong and gave me a system of congruences that had no solution. So Next I try the following

- e --> Y or 4 --> 24
- t --> H or 19 --> 7

Now I set up a system of equations and get α = 21 & β = 18
and this is still wrong! Heres the weird part I ran the text through a brute force search and its telling me that α=11 & β=6.

What could I be doing wrong? I now know for a FACT that e maps to Y and that t maps to H.. and when I set up the system of equations and solve I don't get the right answer..

Comment: You should tell us the meaning of the variables $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but because I'm superhumanly smart at such guessing games let me ask for confimation that the affine cipher does $x\mapsto \alpha x+ \beta\pmod{26}$? So, also assuming English 26 letter alphabet (elsewhere you could get something different). Anyway, that $(11,6)$ is compatible with $e\mapsto Y$ and $s\mapsto W$. Your error seems to be that you didn't stick to the assumption that $W$ is one of the more common letters. Where did that $H$ come from? Where there also like $7$ $H$s in the decrypted string?

Comment: Sorry, α & β are used in the affine cipher encryption so yes αx + β and yes there were 7 Hs in the ENCRYPTED string I should have specified.

Comment: Ok. That's good. So check your congruence algebra. $\alpha=11$, $\beta=6$ gives all of  $e\mapsto Y$,  $s\mapsto W$, and $t\mapsto H$ because $11\cdot4+6\equiv 24$, $11\cdot 18+6\equiv22$, $11\cdot 19+6\equiv7$. It sounds like you just made a numerical error somewhere.

Comment: Hmm.. Why can't get α=11 & β=6. using e -->  Y && t --> H though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your guess that $e=4$ is mapped to $Y=24$ and $t=19$ is mapped to $H=7$ is correct, then the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be solved from the system of congruences (both modulo $26$)
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ccccc}
4\alpha+\beta&\equiv&24,\\
19\alpha+\beta&\equiv&7.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Subtracting the top equation from the bottom one gives
$$
15\alpha\equiv -17\equiv9.
$$
The multiplicative inverse of $15$ modulo $26$ is $7$ (as $7\cdot15=105\equiv1$).
Therefore this implies that
$$
\alpha\equiv105\alpha=7\cdot15\alpha\equiv7\cdot=63\equiv11.
$$
Then we can substitute this back to either equation of the original system and get
$$
\beta\equiv 24-4\alpha=24-44=-20\equiv6
$$
and as a way of confirmation also
$$
\beta\equiv 7-19\alpha=7-19\cdot11=-202\equiv6.
$$

---

Observe that as the most common letters $e$ and $t$ both have an even index, their encrypted versions in an affine cipher will always have the same parity.
As $\gcd(2,26)=2>1$ this implies that there will always be some ambiguity when using that particular pair. Either no solutions at all, or more than one solution.

Comment: One last question. So that means that our decryption function will be Ek(x)=6x + 11 How would I right out the decryption function I dont have an inverse of 6 (mod 26) so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: It's $E_k(x)=11x+6$. And $11\cdot19=209\equiv1$, so $19$ is the inverse.